# AngularJS Select Default Option from Select when user input changes

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

**This question is specific to AngularJS `1.6.5` and above and does not apply to any previous versions.**

I have a form with some `ng-options` selects and some text inputs. When a user selects the `None / Custom` option, a text input appears to the right. Once the user starts typing in that input, the `None / Custom` option is deselected and a new `unknown` option is added.

This is the result of a [bug fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/17d34b7a983a0ef63f6cf404490385c696fb0da1) introduced in AngularJS 1.6.5. Previously when the user typed in the input, the `None / Custom` select remained selected.

**My question is:** how can I recreate the original pre-1.6.5 behavior?

To see an example of what I am talking about, check out these two fiddles. The first fiddle demonstrates the original behavior, the second demonstrates the current (undesired) behavior. Simply select the `None / Custom` option and type something in the adjacent text input.

**Example Fiddles**

[AngularJS 1.6.4 example (good)](http://jsfiddle.net/hstppbj8/341/)

[AngularJS 1.6.5 example (bad)](http://jsfiddle.net/hstppbj8/340/)

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">    
        <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="someCtrl">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="t in utmTags">
                <div class="col-xs-1"><label style="color:#666;">{{t}}</label></div>

                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <select class="form-control flat inline-dropdown skinny" ng-options="o.value as o.key for o in utmOptions" ng-model="company[t]">
                        <option ng-value="company[t]" label="None / Custom"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control flat skinny" style="width:180px;" placeholder="Add tag, without spaces" ng-if="!utmVariables.includes(company[t])" ng-model="company[t]" ng-pattern="utmRegex" />
                    <div ng-if="utmVariables.includes(company[t])">e.g. {{utmOptionsExamples[company[t]]}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.utmOptions = [
        { key: '{AmbassadorFirstNameLastInitialID}', value: '{AmbassadorFirstNameLastInitialID}' },
        { key: '{AdminFirstNameLastInitial}', value: '{AdminFirstNameLastInitial}' },
        { key: '{ContentDomain}', value: '{ContentDomain}' },
        { key: '{ShareDate}', value: '{ShareDate}' },
        { key: '{ShareID}', value: '{ShareID}' },
        { key: '{SocialPlatform}', value: '{SocialPlatform}' }
    ];
    $scope.utmOptionsExamples = {
        '{AmbassadorFirstNameLastInitialID}': 'TracJ-1318',
        '{AdminFirstNameLastInitial}': 'ShanA',
        '{ContentDomain}': 'entrepreneur.com',
        '{ShareDate}': '2017-08-23',
        '{ShareID}': '79131',
        '{SocialPlatform}': 'Twitter'
    };
    $scope.utmRegex = /^[a-z0-9\-\._]*[\{\}]{0}$|^{[a-z0-9\-\._]*}$/i;
    $scope.utmTags = ['utm_medium', 'utm_source', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_term', 'utm_content'];
    $scope.utmVariables = ['{AmbassadorFirstNameLastInitialID}', '{AdminFirstNameLastInitial}', '{ContentDomain}', '{ShareDate}', '{ShareID}', '{SocialPlatform}'];
    $scope.company = {
        utm_medium: undefined,
        utm_source: undefined,
        utm_campaign: undefined,
        utm_term: undefined,
        utm_content: undefined
    }
}]);

app.run();
```

Comment: The input and the select shouldn't be bound to the same model: what you type in the text field is not the value of any of the options of the select, so there's no reason for any option to stay selected.

Comment: I ended up implementing the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/17d34b7a983a0ef63f6cf404490385c696fb0da1#commitcomment-28094330). Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.